# Android button hold to continuously loop a method

Tags: android, button

I have a button and i set a ontouchlistener to continuously execute a method but as i hold on to the button, it stops executing after 1 method call.

my method basically loops from 2 to 4 continuously.

Below is my code snippet.

```
broadcastButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.broadcastButton);
broadcastButton.setText("Loop");
broadcastButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        broadcastmode = 1;
                        schedulePeriodicMethod();
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        broadcastmode = 0;
                        stopPeriodicMethod();


                }
                return true;
            }
        });

public void schedulePeriodicMethod() {
        exHandler.postDelayed(execution, 100);
    }

    public void stopPeriodicMethod() {
        exHandler.removeCallbacks(execution);
    }

    private Runnable execution = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connectDevice(flag);
            serialSend("C");
            flag++;
            if (flag > 4)
                flag = 2;
        }
    };
```

need help on where am i doing wrong that the program is not looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your starting function from

```
public void schedulePeriodicMethod() {
    exHandler.postDelayed(execution, 100);
}
```

to

```
public void schedulePeriodicMethod() {
    exHandler.post(execution);
}
```

and your runnable to :

```
private Runnable execution = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (broadcastmode ==0) return;
        connectDevice(flag);
        serialSend("C");
        flag++;
        if (flag > 4)
            flag = 2;
        //call the runnable itself again, to keep execution going
        exHandler.postDelayed(execution, 100);
    }
};
```

And, as SGal said, your Thread.sleep is totally useless (btw, Thread.sleep in Android is not a good practice, especially on UI Thread)

Comment: Yeah. this method works. Thanks! It executes too fast, so i made the execution interval bigger. But if i need to wait for a certain event to trigger before executing/looping again, how can i do it?

Comment: set a condition on the recall.
But if you have multiple conditions for looping, maybe you don't really need a loop but an on wanted execution? so just delete the recall & call schedulePeriodicMethod() when you want to.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the simple method to loop a method continuously

```
//create a handler, override handle message of Handler
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

// do yo stuffs here like UI update etc. 

//create a new message since a message will be consumed once as it       //delivered by handler after the delay
    Message message = new Message();
    message.what = msg.what;
// send the new message with handler
    myHandler.sendMessageDelayed(message, 150);
// 150 is time in milliseconds after which handler will give callback
    }
    };
```

// let us call the handler on touch of the view, set ontouch listener to //your desired view
//on action down of on touch of the view, create a new message and pass it //to the handler

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    Message message = new Message();
    myHandler.sendMessage(message);
    break;

// on action up of on touch of the view, remove the messages and call backs
//case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    break;
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think `schedulePeriodicMethod();` will call this one time:

```
public void schedulePeriodicMethod() {
        exHandler.postDelayed(execution, 100);
}
```

`postDelayed()` will run one time, so you need to recall it from the method itself

```
public void schedulePeriodicMethod() {
        exHandler.postDelayed(execution, 100);
        schedulePeriodicMethod();
}
```

Comment: tried calling the method again, app crashes once i press the button

Comment: can you post the stacktrace plz

Comment: ofcource! silly me. postDelayed is not blocking, you probably get stack overflow exception. You should call the method from your runnable, but I see @Apollo already posted the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

this is because `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` Fire  simultaneously  when you  Press the Button ,Use this approach

```
MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP = 20 * getActivity().getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics().density;
    @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final int action = event.getAction();
                    switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.d("TAG", "ON Down" + onMoveOccur);
                        onMoveOccur = false;
                        mDownPosX = event.getX();
                        mDownPosY = event.getY();

                      //your code 
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("TAG", "ON UP==" + onMoveOccur);

                        if (!onMoveOccur) {
                            //your code 
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (Math.abs(event.getX() - mDownPosX) > MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP
                                || Math.abs(event.getY() - mDownPosY) > MOVE_THRESHOLD_DP) {
                            onMoveOccur = true;
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove thread sleeping, because it doesn't do anything here and at best makes app skip 6 frames and at worst might even crash some devices since it stops main thread for 100ms

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(100);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And make shadulePeriodicMethod() call it self like

```
public void schedulePeriodicMethod() {
        exHandler.postDelayed(execution, 100);
        if (broadcastmode == 1){
            schedulePeriodicMethod();
        }
}
```

Comment: tried calling the method itself. app crashes once i press the button